# WebStorm: Display ===, != operators as ≡, ≠

Tags: webstorm

I'm looking for a setting/plugin which forces editor to display all occurences of multiple-char equality operators as their corresponding UTF-8 chars (≡, ≠...). I'm sure it is possible  - I saw it on some screenshots from WebStorm. Does anyone know how to turn on this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called **font ligatures**.

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors and Fonts`
3. `Enable font ligatures` -- select this check box to show the typographic ligatures. **Note** that this feature depends on the selected fonts.

---

I could not find dedicated blog post for this new feature .. but you can find some notes here:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-646/
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/07/intellij-idea-2016-2-is-here/
- video: https://youtu.be/Bjq-A4LCU9M?t=23m37s
- Original ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127539

Comment: Thanks for this, I was just looking for name of this "feature". For PhpStorm, Settings -> Editor -> Reader Mode -> Font ligatures, to turn this feature OFF for libraries (vendor) stuff.

Comment: @PeterLaboš Yes, 2020.3 has new Reader Mode that is enabled for read-only/excluded/non-project/library files and has separate settings to what the Editor (Color Scheme) has.